# Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "<viewname>". ResourceRelatedField URL/pk problem (django+rest+json api)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, json-api

## Summary

### Background

I am trying to implement a [JSON:API](https://jsonapi.org/)-compliant general Django app to be used in various projects. I am able to generate decent JSON:API, but I only get "related"-links for one-to-one relationships (foreignkey in the model). I cannot get "related"-links to reverse relationships (other models with a foreign key pointing to my object).

Thank you! //S

### Questions

1. Is ResourceRelatedField the correct way to implement reverse relationship links (e.g. "related")?
2. How do you properly use ResourceRelatedField with related_link_view_name and _url_kwarg?

### Specifics

- I use Django on a ubuntu server (local network) with Django restful framework and Django restful framework json api.
- There are three models in the database: **TopObject**, **Status** and **RelatedObject**.
- **TopObject**-objects has a foreignkey *status* pointing to **Status**
- **RelatedObject**-objects has a foreignkey *topobject* pointing to its 'parent'  **TopObject**-object.
- All of the following url's work properly when entering them manually (e.g. browser or httpie):

  - *localhost:8000/topobjects/1/relatedobjects/* (gives a list of related objects with *topobject* foreignkey = 1)
  - *localhost:8000/topobjects/ (gives list, currently without reverse links. The related link for Status [direct relationship] works).
  - *localhost:8000/topobjects/1/ (gives topobject 1, currently without reverse links. The related link for *status* [direct relationship] works).
  - *localhost:8000/relatedobjects/*
  - *localhost:8000/relatedobjects/1/*
  - *localhost:8000/statuses*
  - *localhost:8000/statuses/1/*
- The view name *topobject-relatedobject-list* works from views when tested with print(reverse...)
- When *related_link_view_name='topobject-relatedobject-list'* is set under ResourceRelatedField, *localhost:8000/relatedobjects/* and *localhost:8000/relatedobjects/1/* raises a Django error.
- I have not figured out how to amend reverse relationship lists within routers/viewsets. Unless that has specific bearing on the problem at hand, I will treat that as a separate issue for later.

## Supporting information

### Target JSON output

```json
            "relationships": {
                "relatedobjects": {
                    "meta": {
                        "count": 2
                    },
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "type": "relatedobject",
                            "id": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "relatedobject",
                            "id": "2"
                        }
                    ],
//***************MISSING**************//
                    "links": {
                      "related": "http://192.168.0.152:8000/topobjects/1/relatedobjects"
                    }
//***************END MISSING**************//
                },
                "status": {
                    "data": {
                        "type": "status",
                        "id": "1"
                    },
                    "links": {
                        "related": "http://192.168.0.152:8000/statuses/1/"
                    }
                }
            },
```

### serializers.py

```python
from rest_framework_json_api import serializers
from .models import TopObject, Status, RelatedObject
from rest_framework_json_api.relations import ResourceRelatedField

class RelatedObjectSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = RelatedObject
        fields = '__all__'

class TopObjectSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    related_serializers = {'relatedobjects': 'api.serializers.RelatedObjectSerializer', 'status': 'api.serializers.StatusSerializer'}

    relatedobjects = ResourceRelatedField(
        queryset=RelatedObject.objects,
        many=True,
        related_link_view_name='topobject-relatedobject-list',
        related_link_url_kwarg='pk'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = TopObject
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_fields = ['relatedobjects', 'testrelated']

class StatusSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Status
        fields ='__all__'
```

### urls.py

```python
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import url

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'topobjects', views.TopObjectViewSet)
router.register(r'statuses', views.StatusViewSet)
router.register(r'relatedobjects', views.RelatedObjectViewSet)

topobjectsrelatedobjects = views.TopObjectRelatedObjectViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list', 'post': 'create'})

urlpatterns = [
    path('topobjects/<int:pk>/relatedobjects/', topobjectsrelatedobjects, name='topobject-relatedobject-list'),
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Is ResourceRelatedField the correct way to implement reverse relationship links (e.g. "related")?
   *Yes. This is the standard in Django REST json api.*
2. How do you properly use ResourceRelatedField with related_link_view_name and _url_kwarg?
   *As the framework uses the queryset model name (i.e. 'RelatedObject') as a basis for the kwarg called **related_fields**, the **url.conf** must accept the following:*

```
path('topobjects/<int:pk>/<related_field>/', views.TopObjectView.as_view(), name='topobject-relatedobject-list'),
```

The following url.conf will not work in this example:

```
path('topobjects/<int:pk>/relatedobjects/', views.TopObjectView.as_view(), name='topobject-relatedobject-list'),
```

The forward url would work in the second example, but not the reverse that ResourceRelatedField relies on.